# Xcode 9 Beta - Unable to add new Playground page

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, xcode9-beta, xcode9

In Xcode 9 Beta, I have created a new Playground **(File -> New -> Playground**). Now, when I am adding a new Playground page **(File -> New -> Playground Page)**, it is not added/shown.
Is this a bug ?

Comment: Yes, it's been reported to Apple already. It's bug in the beta.

Comment: I am using Xcode8 and Xcode9-beta together. I follow these solution steps. I have CleanMyMac app. This app cleans all temp and derived data and restart MacOS. That's right. There is a big performance problem. But These steps work for me.

Answer (score 14):

I am running into the same problem in beta and the final release of Xcode 9.0. As states in Release note below. Now I am using 2 steps to solve the issue.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html ,

In Xcode menu, select File -> New -> Playground, Xcode will open window for you to choose a template.

[image]

Selecting one of the templates and navigate to your project folder to save (first it will take you to a location that is nowhere near your existing project folder ,this should be fixed !). Once hit save the playground file will open (mine open in a new window),  close that window. Next in ProjectNavigator, right click on your project or a group under project (wherever you want the playground to be added in the first place) . Select 'Add file To YourProjectName'. Choose the playground file you just created and click 'ok'. Your playground should be included now.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why they moved Playgrounds out of the new file options.

Answer (score 1):

**In XCode 9, I can create New Page under existing playground by right-clicking on playground and Select "New Playground Page" as shown in below  screenshot.**

[image]